# How to search more than one options on click on submit through ransack search

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ransack

i want to search both category and location on click on search(Ransack)

my view

```
<%= form_tag location_path, :method=>'get' do %> 
<%= select_tag :q, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name, params[:q]) %>
<%= text_field_tag :q, nil,:placeholder=>"Tell us what you are looking for.." %>
<input type="submit" value="SEARCH" class="btn1 home-search-button" >
<% end %>
```

This is my view of this form
[image]
my searchcontroller is

```
def location
    q = params[:q]
    @key=q
    @property = Property.ransack(location_or_category_name_cont: q).result(distinct: true)
  end

this search searches only location not category,
on executing i am getting like this, 
`url is like this : http://localhost:3000/location?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=2&q=banglore`
```

command iam getting on executing
[image]`
Here it is searching banglore as category name and location(it should search 'commercial' as category_name(which is under category_id:2) instaed of banglore'

Any help is appreciatable

now i am getting like this, seach query is wrong
`[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<%= form_tag location_path, :method=>'get' do %> 
<%= select_tag :category_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, :id, :name, params[:q]) %>
<%= text_field_tag :q, nil,:placeholder=>"Tell us what you are looking for.." %>
<input type="submit" value="SEARCH" class="btn1 home-search-button" >
<% end %>
```

try this

You are using same parameter name for location as well as for category and which is getting overridden.

Comment: no some query error. i updated my terminal screen shot above. please check

Comment: previously the your category id was not passing as params..right? that issue is resolved now

Answer (score 0):

not sure what version of ransack you are using but according to documentation [ransack](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack), following would fix the problem.

in your view, should use the search_form_for helper

```
<%= search_form_for @q do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :category_name_cont %>
  <%= f.select :category_name_cont, options_from_collection_for_select(Category.all, "name", "name", @q.category_name_cont) %>

  <%= f.label :location_name_cont %>
  <%= f.search_field :location_name_cont %>

  <%= f.submit %>

<% end %>
```

and in your controller

```
def location
    @q = Property.ransack(params[:q]).result(distinct: true)
end
```